# Get index of element in page based on type of tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the index of each element in a page when clicked. But the point is that the index should not be the general index of the item, it should be based on the type of tag.

For example, consider the below example. I have provided the current value I am getting and also the expected output.

```
<div>First Div</div> <!-- This shows 0 (as required) -->
<div>Second Div</div> <!-- This shows 1 (as required) -->
<div>Third Div</div> <!-- This shows 2 (as required) -->
<div>
    <p>First Para</p> <!-- This shows 0 (as required) -->
    <p>Second Para</p> <!-- This shows 1 (as required) -->
    <span>First Span</span> <!-- This shows 2 but I need it as 0 -->
    <br/>
    <span>Second Span</span> <!-- This shows 4 but I need it as 1 -->
</div>
<p>Third Para</p> <!-- This shows 4 but I need it as 2-->
<span>Third Span</span> <!-- This shows 5 but I need it as 2 -->
```

The below is the code that I have tried so far. How should this be modified to fit my requirements?

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   index = $(this).index();
   console.log(index); 
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvN2j/1/) with the current code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is getting the index of each tag with respect to its parent. You need to modify it as below to get the index of the currently clicked element based on the tag type.

```
index = $(this.tagName).index(this);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VtZJX/)

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Can't believe it is so simple. I was breaking my head for an hour.... feels very dumb *facepalm*